# Will using the ZipArchive class give Apple reason to reject my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a .zip file that contains sub-directories with html,png, and css files in my iPad App.  The .zip file is included as a Support File that gets copied to the Documents Directory on startup. I have read about multiple methods for extracting compressed files locally and I have found ZipArchive class to be most convenient solution for me.

Does anyone know if Apple may/will reject my iPad app for implementing ZipArchive in my application?

Comment: I am not sure about ZipArchive, however, you can no longer dump files into the Documents directory. With 5.0 this directory is stored in iCloud, and is only to be used for user generated content. Instead, you should be using /Library/Caches

Comment: Even if it will contain permanent content required by the application and extra downloadable content that should be saved in iCloud?

Comment: I just recently had an app update rejected for putting required assets in Documents. Anything that can be redownloaded, restored (i.e. anything that is not user defined, generated or modified) should not go into Documents. It should go into Caches. Caches lives as long as the app is installed, it's not cleared until the app is uninstalled.

Comment: There's an [Apple tech note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) on the use of the various folders

Comment: Section 2.23 Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected           1. Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the /Documents directory and will be automatically backed up by iCloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, no Apple will not reject your app for using ZipArchive.

However, the location that you unzip the archive to is important, as Apple will reject the app if you litter the Documents folder with your assets.

You should use one of the Library folders, possibly Caches.

The caches folder, *will be purged* in low storage situations, according to the [Tech Note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) on the subject. But in that case, you'll still have the zip archive in your app bundle, you can just unzip it again if it gets purged.

Comment: Thank you. This is refreshing to hear as far as the allowance of ZipArchive.

Comment: Concerning the storage use of the Documents directory, wouldn't it be allowed to be flagged with a Do Not Backup attribute since my files are required offline content? Referenced from Q&A: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) under Offline Data.

Comment: You could possibly get away with that, as it seems to be permitted, according to the Tech Note.